# Get data from Active Directory using react and ASP.NET Core

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, active-directory, ldap, asp.net-core-webapi

Can someone share code to retrieve user details along with thumbnail image to be displayed on the basis of an input of a `SamAccountName`?

This has to be accomplished using ASP.NET Core and react. I am pretty new to these technologies, please help.

### My trials as below

Controller code:

```
public Image ourTeam()
    {
        var userDetails = db.users.Where(x=>x.saMAccountName == "someUsername").FirstOrDefault();

        Image image = GetImage(userDetails.CN); //I get image data
        //context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();

        if (image != null)
            image.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

        return image;
    }
```

Component code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router';

interface FetchImageDataState {
imageList: ImageData[];
loading: boolean;
}

export class OurTeam extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, FetchImageDataState> {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { imageList: [], loading: true }; //initialize to default

    fetch('api/Home/ourTeam')
        .then(response => response.json() as Promise<ImageData[]>)
        .then(data => {
            this.setState({ imageList: data, loading: false });
        });
}

    public render() {

    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : this.renderImageTable(this.state.imageList);
    return <div>
        <h1>Team</h1>


        {contents}
    </div>;
}

private renderImageTable(imageList: ImageData[]) {
    return <div className='table'>{
        imageList.map(x =>
            <img src={x.byteData} alt={x.CN} />)
    }</div>;


}
}

export class ImageData {
CN: string = "";
byteData: string = "";
}
```

PFB the code on how I am authenticating and then retrieving image:

```
private Image GetImage(string cn)
    {
        string LDAP_PATH = "LDAP://" + "SOMEPATH.com";
        string user = "USERID";
        string password = "PASSWORD";
                    using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(LDAP_PATH, user, password))
        {
            {
                DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
                search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");
                search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + cn + "))";
                SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
                if (result == null)
                {
                    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(cn=" + cn + "))";
                    result = search.FindOne();
                }

                if (result != null)
                {
                    DirectoryEntry entryUser = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
                    string propertyName = "thumbnailPhoto";
                    if (entryUser.Properties.Contains(propertyName))
                    {
                        byte[] img = entryUser.Properties[propertyName].Value as byte[];
                        MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(img);
                        return Image.FromStream(memStream);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // User not authenticated
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: There is lots of stuff that can be found using Google about [how to read Active Directory from ASP.NET Core](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+read+active+directory+from+asp.net+core)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am able to connect and authenticate in Active Directory. The issue I am facing is displaying the details along with image of the user in react. Not sure if a middleware is to be added or just controller can work.

Comment: How are you authenticating? Are you using Windows Authentication, or using LDAP directly?

Comment: Hi - I have updated the post to display how I am authenticating..

Comment: SHOCKED TO SEE THERE IS NO ONE WITH THIS EXPERTISE.........

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to return the image as if you were just downloading a file.

First, return a `byte[]` from `GetImage`. You don't gain anything here by converting it to an `Image` object. If you needed to edit the image in code, then it would make sense. But since you're not, it doesn't matter.

So change this:

```
byte[] img = entryUser.Properties[propertyName].Value as byte[];
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream(img);
return Image.FromStream(memStream);
```

To this:

```
return entryUser.Properties[propertyName].Value as byte[];
```

Then in your controller, return a [`FileContentResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.filecontentresult?view=aspnetcore-3.1), like this:

```
public ActionResult ourTeam()
{
    var userDetails = db.users.Where(x=>x.saMAccountName == "someUsername").FirstOrDefault();

    byte[] image = GetImage(userDetails.CN);

    return File(image, "image/jpeg");
}
```

Comment: I made the changes suggested by you in the controller page. The image doesn't load after running the application, I get below error due to some error in react code probably:
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token � in JSON at position 0

Comment: Your code as you have it is expecting a JSON response, but it's getting a file instead. You'll have to change your code to expect an image file. I'm not a React developer though, so I don't think I can help you with that.

Comment: That's a sad news for me and my issue.. 